# ¿como puedo pasar un codigo javascript a jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Realicé el siguiente código el cual me funciona perfecto... pero me exigen el uso de `jQuery`. Aún estoy aprendiendot, así que me es difícil cambiarlo.

He logrado cambiar solo el `alert` inicial pero no logro hacer que funcione guiándome con lo encontrado en la api.

```js
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");
const Container = document.getElementById("listContainer");

function addTask() {
  if (inputBox.value == '') {
    alert("Debes escribir una tarea");
  } else {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = inputBox.value;
    Container.appendChild(li);
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = "\u00d7";
    li.appendChild(span);
  }
  inputBox.value = '';
  saveData();
}
```

```html
// estan son las clases y funciones que estoy ejecutando


<div class="taskContainer">
  <div class="taskApp">
    <h2>Lista de Tareas <img src="images/icon.png"></h2>
    <div class="newTask">
      <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="agregar Tarea">
      <button onclick="addTask()">Agregar</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="listContainer">
    </ul>
```

Comment: Supongo que puedes reemplazar todos los selectores "getElement..." y los "createElements", por sus corresponientes funciones $("#id") ... .append... etc

Comment: Esto me recuerda a ["no es suficiente jQuery"](https://needsmorejquery.com/) :)

Comment: Si es tema de trabajo y te "exigen" el uso de JQuery, yo iría viendo otras ofertas de trabajo y preparando el CV. Ojo, esto es una opinión totalmente personal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo el ejemplo comentado con la sintaxis de `jQuery`. Si tienes algua duda puntual sobre alguna de las funciones, deja un comentario y con gusto intentaré resolverla.

```js
function addTask() {
  //Capturar el value de input-box
  let inputBox = $("#input-box").val();
  //Validar si llega vacío
  if (inputBox == '') {
    alert("Debes escribir una tarea");
  } else {
    //Maquetar el li con el span incluido
    let elemento = "<li>" + inputBox + " <span>\u00d7</span></li>";
    //Agregar el elemento a la lista
    $("#listContainer").append(elemento);
  }
  //Vaciar el value de input-box
  $("#input-box").val('');
  //saveData();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="taskContainer">
  <div class="taskApp">
    <h2>Lista de Tareas <img src="images/icon.png"></h2>
    <div class="newTask">
      <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="agregar Tarea">
      <button onclick="addTask()">Agregar</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="listContainer">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un identificador en tu botón para capturarlo desde jQuery y especificar que si se hizo clic en el botón, ejecute la función `addTask()`:

```html
<button id="add-button">Agregar</button>
```

Y en jQuery:

```
$('#add-button').click(function() {
  addTask();
});
```

Respecto con lo demás, te adjunto un ejemplo que hace exactamente lo mismo que el código JavaScript que tenías hecho (explicación en comentarios):

```js
$('#add-button').click(function() {
  addTask();
});

function addTask() {
  // vamos a capturar a tus elementos
  const inputBox = $('#input-box');
  const container = $('#listContainer');
  // si el valor de tu input es vacío, muestro el alert
  if (inputBox.val() === '') {
    alert("Debes escribir una tarea");
  } else {
    // de lo contrario, creamos una nueva etiqueta <li>, que contendrá como texto el valor de tu input.
    let li = $('<li>').text(inputBox.val());
    // e insertamos ese elemento al contenedor "container".
    container.append(li);
    // ahora creamos un span, que tendrá como texto el simbolo "X".
    let span = $('<span>').html('\u00d7');
    // e insertamos ese elemento al nuevo "li" creado.
    li.append(span);
  }
  // y por último borramos el valor del input.
  inputBox.val('');
  // saveData();
}
```

```html
<div class="taskContainer">
  <div class="taskApp">
    <h2>Lista de Tareas <img src="images/icon.png"></h2>
    <div class="newTask">
      <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="agregar Tarea">
      <button id="add-button">Agregar</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="listContainer"></ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```